# include(OAuth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory error in Yiidropbox extension

Tags: oauth, yii, dropbox, yii-extensions

When I tried to run

```
$dropbox = Yii::app()->dropbox;
```

as mentioned in http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiidropbox/#hh1 , I am getting the error  `include(OAuth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`  . What is causing this error?

Comment: Have u checked the settings in config file that it is getting the correct path to the file OAuth.php file ??

Comment: The doc just instructs to add
'components'=>array(
    ...

    'dropbox' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.YiiDropbox.YiiDropbox',
        'appKey' => 'YOUR APP KEY',
        'appSecret' => 'YOUR SECRET KEY',
        'root' => 'dropbox' //or 'sandbox'
    ),

    ...
);
in main.php file

Comment: It is not getting the class OAuth In YiiDropbox 
 $this->_oauth = new OAuth($this->appKey, $this->appSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);

Comment: The extension has only one file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the [PHP OAuth extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php). You can install it through PECL or maybe even as a package (depends on your operating system). For example on Ubuntu you would

```
sudo apt-get install liboauth-php
```